# What namespace holds information on the SQL Server TinyInt datatype?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have this code:

```
DataTable answers = new DataTable();
answers.Columns.Add("Response", typeof(TinyInt));
foreach (AnswerRow a in answer.AnswerRows)
{
    answers.Rows.Add(a.Response);
}
```

However it is giving me an error with TinyInt saying the "type or namespace cannot be found"

Does anyone know what I need to include to make it so that I can use this?

Here's my current includes?

```
using Entities.Models.Core;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Models.Http;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using WebRole1.Helpers;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using WebRole1.Filters;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data;
```

Comment: There is no such type. The .NET equivalent is a `byte`. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx

Answer (score 2):

`TinyInt` of SQL Server would map to [`Byte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693.aspx) in C#.

See: [Mapping CLR Parameter Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

So for your code you need:

```
answers.Columns.Add("Response", typeof(byte));
```